# Dotnet EF migrations add is not working in mediatoR pattern

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am working on one project in which is following mediatoR design pattern. Database SQL and it is a code first approach. I have 4 layers

- Web.UI
- Application
- Infrastructure
- Domain
- **Web.UI layer** has controllers and appsettings.json files
- **Application Layer** has services and CRUD operations
- **Domain Layer** has all the entities
- **Infrastructure Layer**
  has DbContext i.e. all the tables inside which i need to run the below command
  dotnet ef migrations add initialCreate

When i run command using Web.UI as project I get the below expected error message:

**Your startup project 'Web.UI' doesn't reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is correct, install the package, and try again**.

However when i run the command using Infrastructure as project were all the ef references and other things are added i get the below error message:
**The configuration file 'appsettings.json'** was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was Infrastructure/appsettings.json

Can anyone please help me? Early response is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time :). I found the solution for this.

1. Deleted the appsettings.json file from Web.UI project
2. Added the appsettings.json file inside Infrastructure project
3. Re-added as existing item and 'Add as link' option from file explorer inside Web.UI project just for reference
4. Refrence Link: [Visual Studio Share File between multiple projects](https://makolyte.com/visual-studio-share-a-file-between-multiple-projects/)